# how to save pdf,word or text "FILES" in mySQL with qt creator

Tags: mysql, qt, file, pdf, transfer

Well there is only the possibility to create a pdf or word file in my qt creator 5.14.2 but i searched to find a connection between my files and database.

I only know that you have to use `Binary or BLOB` at the mysql database to transfer the pdf in the database.

i have the code for the creating it to the local computer (mine) this is the code for creating a text file and it is working.

```
QFile file ("C:/Documents/project/text.txt");
if (!file.open(QFile::WriteOnly | QFile::Text))
    QMessageBox::warning(this,"title","file not open");
    QTextStream out (&file);
    QString text=ui->Dokutextfeld->toPlainText();
    out << text;
    file.flush();
    file.close();
```

Any ideas how to save files into database and also can recall them to the program in qt?

Comment: Did you check the [data storage](https://doc.qt.io/qt-5/topics-data-storage.html) section in the Qt documentation?

Comment: i found nothing to this specific case.. i was also on qt documentation :/

Comment: fileNameDok = ui->Dokutitel->toPlainText();
    filePathDok = ui->Dokutitel->toPlainText();
    fileNameDok=fileNameDok.trimmed();
    filePathDok =filePathDok.trimmed();
    QString Textfeld = ui->Dokutextfeld->toPlainText();
    QByteArray inByteArray = Textfeld.toUtf8();
    fileTypeDok.append("txt");
    dbverbindung->saveFileTxt(fileNameDok, inByteArray, fileTypeDok, VersicherungsnummerDok);
    this->hide();